# Apple Airpods as microphone in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, microphone, apple

I've just acquired **Apple Airpods** (2nd gen) to use it as my main sound setup in **Ubuntu 20.04**  since I'm WFH in order to use them in Zoom meetings and so on but is not possible.

Ubuntu 20.04 is not able to detect the microphone and there's **no way to use them as a microphone**.

Any idea how to fix that? If they are not gonna work I'll return them since they are pretty expensive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I too have this problem - audio is fine but mic is not detected. Tried reverting /etc/pulse/default.pa from an earlier DEB package & also obviously tried switching the mode in sound settings to HSP/HFP - but nothing happens.